# Influx CLI driving me really crazy, cannot open the CLI

Tags: influxdb, ubuntu-20.04, influxdb-2

i am installing the influxdb_2.0.9 on my ubuntu, i followed the instructions here:

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/install/?t=Linux

I download it, setup it, i start the influxd daemon, i can connect via browser on localhost:8086, i think i can work with it, its functioning, i am gonna use the python API anyway, but this really drives me crazy...

I can't get to CLI. When i copy it to /usr/local/bin, or anywhere, or when i run it right in the directory via ./influx, it just returns a HELP message, like if i would type ./influx -h

Funny thing is when i download influxdb-client and run its influx binary, it starts the CLI, but its meant on version 1.6.4 and it does not seem to connect ideally on localhost running influxd 2.0.9, mbe i could somehow config it, but it seems to be bad idea anyway.

I purged everything, tried to reinstall everything, even manually deleted all empty directories, anything named *influx* on my 20.04 Ubuntu is gone and when i try to just follow the instructions online, everything seems to work except the CLI which i really **** need.

Just FYI, if i try to isntall via sudo apt-get install influxdb, influxdb-client -> it works perfectly, but it is older version 1.6.4

I tried installing the deb package via dpkg as well, but no difference... Im running 20.04 Ubuntu. There is the option of running older influxdb(1.6.x), but that I really dont want to do.

Anyone had the same problem? Could not find the solution in last hour online so im trying here to find help. This really drives me crazy though... Thanks for your time. Q.

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i seem to realize, that the old CLI is gone and not implemented as it used to be, in the new version. In 2.0.0 it was started by

```
influx repl
```

But now i found a msg[image]

I have no idea why they decided to deprecate this, not posting that much info about it..
I will try to finish this post by myself, leave it here, maybe someone in the future will find this useful.

Now I will try to 'build the REPL from source', wish me luck lol.

--EDIT
found a clone, closing the thread.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/19986